# Pyspark Single RDD to Multiple RDD by Key from RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, data-manipulation

I am new to Pyspark, I am using Spark 2.0.2.

I have RDD called Test_RDD with following structure:

```
U-Key  ||  V1  ||  V2  ||  V3  ||
-----------------------------------

1001_01  ||  12  ||  41   ||  21  ||

1001_01  ||  36  ||  43   ||  63  ||

1001_01  ||  60  ||  45   ||  10  ||

1002_03  ||  84  ||  57   ||  14  ||

1002_03  ||  18  ||  49   ||  18  ||

1004_01  ||  12  ||  41   ||  22  ||

1004_01  ||  16  ||  43   ||  26  ||
```

I need to create new RDD from unique values available on U-Key column, for example

RDD_1001_01 as:

```
U-Key  ||  V1  ||  V2  ||  V3  ||
-----------------------------------
1001_01  ||  12  ||  41   ||  21  ||

1001_01  ||  36  ||  43   ||  63  ||

1001_01  ||  60  ||  45   ||  10  ||
```

RDD_1002_03 as:

```
U-Key  ||  V1  ||  V2  ||  V3  ||
-----------------------------------

1002_03  ||  84  ||  57   ||  14  ||

1002_03  ||  18  ||  49   ||  18  ||
```

RDD_1004_01 as:

```
U-Key  ||  V1  ||  V2  ||  V3  ||
-----------------------------------

1004_01  ||  12  ||  41   ||  22  ||

1004_01  ||  16  ||  43   ||  26  ||
```

From 1 RDD (Test_RDD) to 3 RDD's (RDD_1001_01, RDD_1002_03, RDD_1004_01),
new RDD's name should be like RDD_(Unique Column name from Test_RDD). Is there any function available for this scenario in Pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @user6910411, it is not possible to do this with a single function call.

Despite your answer, the post actually does provide a significant amount of insight on your problem: The first sentence of the answer already states

> It is not possible to yield multiple RDDs from a single transformation*. If you want to split a RDD you have to apply a filter for each split condition.

Aside from that, you could theoretically do this by splitting for each of the individual indices - not something you want to do for a possibly large RDD.
Instead, a simple `groupByKey` could do the trick to achieve something similar to your request, but within the same RDD. Depending on your further processing, it should be mentioned that you [should avoid groupByKey for reduce operations](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html), due to its excessive amount of shuffle operations.